# Problemas con jQuery y css en angular2

Tags: jquery, css3, angularjs-2.0

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web en **angular2** donde esta formada por la siguiente estructura: una cabecera, un menú lateral izquierdo desplegable, el contenido de la app en la parte derecha y un footer al final.

Mi problema es como lograr que el height del menú siempre llegue hasta el footer cuando el contenido de la página es muy grande y que cuando el contenido de la página sea muy pequeño el footer se quede en el pie de la pantalla.

He visto varios ejemplos de realizar esto con **jQuery** que funcionan bien cada vez que se recarga la página o con el *`$(window).resize(function () {})`*; pero como en angular su contenido cambia sin recargar la página no me funcionan.

Quisiera que alguien me mostrara un ejemplo de como realizar esto en **angular2**. Saludos

Comment: yo hago un truco por que angular no rendereriza, esto te servira para otras cosas, lo que hago es ocultar el elemento y no mostrarlo hasta que se termine de llenar la(s) variables(s) me ha funcionado de maravilla

Comment: puedes compartir tu truco?

Comment: tu problema es que no se ajusta a la pantalla?

Comment: no, el problema es que cuando el contenido de la página es muy grande él height del menú llegue hasta el footer, porque como lo tengo ahora, se queda muy corto en ese caso, el objetivo es que el color de fondo llegue hasta abajo. Me entiendes?

Comment: entonces tu problema no es angular ni jQuery(ambas lo pueden solucionar) tu problema es de hojas de estilo! aun asi hagas la repuesta que te dieron no te va a funcionar y tampoco mi comentario lo que debes hacer es agregar el css y mostrar la pantalla alguna persona te ayudara con el estilo

Comment: aunque la respuesta que te dieron es valida por que te explicaron como usar el resize, no es lo que necesitas!

Comment: no me funciona esa respuesta. El problema es que esa función se dispara cada vez que cambia de tamaño la página en la pantalla. Y lo que me interesaría es un evento que se dispare cada vez que el alto de un div se modifique por ejemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero, no juntes jQuery y Angular, o uno o el otro.

Lo segundo, prueba con esto y me dices.

```
<div (window:resize)="onResize($event)">
```

+

```
onResize(event) {
  event.target.innerWidth;
}
```

o

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
  event.target.innerWidth;
}
```

Suponiendo que los traget globales son `window`, `document`, and `body`.

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527456/angular-window-resize-event)

Comment: Sólo la primera frase ya se merece un voto

Comment: Pero con esa función ¿no estaría cogiendo los detalles de la pantalla?